# Opening Abiword files

Tags: 12.04, abiword

Abiword files no longer (12.04) open themselves, but need to be called by the main menu to do so - with Abiword (what else!) My finger is so used to the double click on the file name to open it, that it does it automatically, and now has to be corrected with a few  more clicks. Can I have a macro, or its equivalent, to make my second click still do the job?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a Abiword file and select preferences in the menu. Select Abiword in the field where it says it will open the file with this application. This should fix all Abiword files so that they open in Abiword with a double left-click.